# podcast for WebOS development?

Tags: podcast, webos, palm-pre, mojo-sdk

Are there any podcasts for WebOS (Palm Mojo) development?

Answer (score 1):

The [mobility today podcasts](http://mobilitytoday.com/archive.php?c=22&type=n) has a palm-pre user as one of its hosts. From the one I've listened now it has good technical depth (though not developer specific) but they cover a very wide range of (mobile)platforms.

And there is the [pre central podcast](http://www.precentral.net/pre-podcast/), but that also targets users so might be even less developer oriented.